# How to select distinct from union result with condition

Tags: sql-server, select, distinct, union

I want to select distinct vendor with chase if there are two vendor with status register and not register then the choosen one is vendor with status register but if only one vendor then just select it,

I'm using sql server 2017

```
SELECT
 pv.vendor_id,pv.vendor_name,'Not Registered' as registration_status
    FROM 
        proposal_vendor as pv
    UNION
SELECT      bv.vendor_id,bv.vendor_name,bv.registration_status
    FROM 
        bidding_vendor as bv
    WHERE 
        bv.bidding_header_id = 97

48  vendor a               Register
48  vendor a           Not Registered   
4110    vendor b               Register
4110    vendor b               Not Registered   
4197    vendor c               Not Registered
```

what i'm expected is

```
48  vendor a        Register
4110    vendor b            Register
4197    vendor c        Not Registered
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT pv.vendor_id,
       pv.vendor_name,
       'Not Registered' as registration_status
    FROM proposal_vendor as pv
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                         FROM bidding_vendor bv
                         WHERE bv.vendor_id = pv.vendor_id
                             AND bv.bidding_header_id = 97)
UNION ALL
SELECT bv.vendor_id,
       bv.vendor_name,
       bv.registration_status
    FROM bidding_vendor as bv
    WHERE bv.bidding_header_id = 97
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get your expected output using row number and case statement. If you have two registered then you can use rank, else you can use row number if you want just one row per vendor id.

```
select vendor_id, vendor_name, registration_status from  (
SELECT      bv.vendor_id,bv.vendor_name,bv.registration_status, row_number() over (partition by bv.vendor_id order by case when registration_status = 'Register' then 1 else 2) rownum 
    FROM 
        bidding_vendor as bv) t
where t.rownum = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple possibilities here.

You can make your main query a derived table source for your results query

```
SELECT pv.vendor_id, 
    pv.vendor_name, MAX(registration_status) as registration_status
FROM (
    SELECT
     pv.vendor_id,pv.vendor_name,'Not Registered' as registration_status
        FROM 
            proposal_vendor as pv
        UNION
    SELECT      bv.vendor_id,bv.vendor_name,bv.registration_status
        FROM 
            bidding_vendor as bv
        WHERE 
            bv.bidding_header_id = 97
    ) src
```

You can use Outer Join logic

```
SELECT pv.vendor_id, 
    pv.vendor_name, 
    CASE WHEN bv.vendor_id is null
        THEN 'Not '
    END + 'Registered' as registration_status
FROM proposal_vendor as pv
FULL OUTER JOIN bidding_vendor as bv
    ON pv.vendor_id = bv.vendor_id
WHERE pv.vendor_id = 97
    OR bv.vendor_id = 97
```

Or you can choose another from perhaps a half dozen different techniques.